# Java calling a list of models

Tags: java, methods

I am very new in this whole java programming thing and struggle with a rather simple issue. If you could help me out I would be very thankful.

In my engine I want to add a bunch of game objects (.obj files) but since this code is going to be rather extensive I want to have a seperate class for it.

Now my question is how do I have to write the code so that I can call a method or something from the other class that has the list of all game objects?

Here's what I mean:

in Class EngineSetup, this is where I want to call the comented out code..

```
public class EngineSetup extends Game
{
    public void Init()
    {   

    Call the method public void TileSet1() in class 2 but how?

        //GameObject Tile0 = new GameObject();
        //Mesh mesh = new Mesh("Tile1.obj");
        //Material material = new Material
        //(new Texture("GrassUV.png"), 1, 8);
        //MeshRenderer meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, material);
        //Tile0.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
        //Tile0.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(0, 0, 0);
        //AddObject(Tile0);

        //GameObject Tile1 = new GameObject();
        //meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, material);
        //Tile1.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
        //Tile1.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(10, 0, 0);
        //AddObject(Tile1);
    }
}
```

in class TileSets, this is where all the comented out code should be called from instead..

```
public class TileSets extends Game 
{
    public void TileSet1()
    {
        GameObject Tile0 = new GameObject();
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh("Tile1.obj");
        Material material = new Material
        (new Texture("GrassUV.png"), 1, 8);
        MeshRenderer meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, material);
        Tile0.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
        Tile0.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(0, 0, 0);
        AddObject(Tile0);

        GameObject Tile1 = new GameObject();
        meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, material);
        Tile1.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
        Tile1.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(10, 0, 0);
        AddObject(Tile1);   
    }
}
```

here's an example of what I've tried and the result of it.. I must be missing something..??

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-27669317/example.png.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for you help, I've emailed someone who understands the engine a bit better than me and he gave me the following solution:

apparently the problem was that I tried to make TileSets extend the game class and this wouldn't work for I what I wanted to do, instead I should do it like so:

In TileSets I have to make the class just manipulate Game instead of extending it..

```
public class TileSets
{   
 private Game game;

 public TileSets(Game game)
 {
 this.game = game;
 }

 public void Terrain()
 {
 GameObject Tile0 = new GameObject();
 Mesh mesh = new Mesh("Tile1.obj");
 Material material = new Material
 (new Texture("GrassUV.png"), 1, 8);
 MeshRenderer meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, material);
 Tile0.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
 Tile0.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(0, 0, 0);
 game.AddObject(Tile0); 
 }
}
```

In EngineSetup I am then able to use this method and everything works out :)

```
public class EngineSetup extends Game
{       
    public void Init()
    {           
// ALL TILES
    TileSets tilesets = new TileSets(this);
    tilesets.Terrain(); 
    }
}
```

Thanks for the effort anyways and I hope someone else will be able to find my solution useful.

Here's the final result: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-27690147/ExTerrain.png.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of TileSets in EngineSetup & call your method TileSet1()

```
public class EngineSetup extends Game
    {

    TileSets tileSetObj = new TileSets();
    public void Init()
        {
        tileSetObj.TileSet1(); //calls the TileSets TileSet1 method code
       }
    }
```

Comment: yes thanks, that's what I thought too but for some reason this doesn't work for me - I'm using eclipse by the way but that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: what is the error? Using eclipse would rather help you reduce the errors :)

Comment: put a debugger on your code. You'll get an understanding of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EngineSetup extends Game {
    //Create tilesets object of type TileSets
    TileSets tilesets = new TileSets();
    public void Init() {   
       // Call the method TileSet1() here.
       tilesets.TileSet1();
    }
}
```